# exec/system() - script being called works until called from PHP

Tags: php, external-process

I have a bash script:

run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/project/bin/ 
CMD="./executable <full_path_to_file>;
$CMD
```

When I run this program from the terminal. (i.e. `./run.sh`, it works fine)

However when I call it from PHP:

```
system("full_path_to_sh_file", $out);
```

It calls the script successfully, and even runs the executable, but now the executable throws an error saying that the supplied file can't be found.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it the script file that cant be found or a file call in the sh script?

Comment: The file specified by <full_path_to_file> that the executable reads. Also note that it is a full_path not relative. and that this script runs when executed from the terminal (i.e. not from PHP)

Comment: what's the permissions on the file?

Comment: I gave all the files 777 permissions just to see if it was a permissions issue. It was a permissions issue ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How do you run PHP script, from webserver or command line?
2. If from webserver, what user is it run (httpd or apache?)
3. Make sure the environment as same as when you are running from terminal (for example: same user)
4. Try this if running as different user: 
   `sudo -u apache /fullpath/run.sh`

Comment: 1. Running from webserver. 2. apache

Comment: As to the user/permission and step 4. give me a bit and i'll give it a look. :) thanks.

Comment: Good god.. it was a permissions issue. :) Thanks again